# Indexing a column with different formats of UUID (V4 and V7)

Tags: mysql, indexing, uuid

From my understanding of UUID v7 they are binary sortable which in some way improves indexability. My database is currently storing v4 UUIDs in an indexed column, if I start storing new rows with UUID v7 will I still gain the indexing benefits even if the column has other non sortable rows? What is the best data type to use for this row, currently it is a char(36)

Comment: No   UUID7 is not easier to index, but it is easier to sort, assuming the engine knows about it.  MySQL probably uses some kind of tree for indexing, and if anything UUID7 makes that harder, because the first set of digits will always be the same.  More collisions.

Comment: See [MySQL & UUIDs](https://lefred.be/content/mysql-uuids/).

Comment: @TimRoberts - A BTree is a BTree; UUIDs can only be used as a point query.  The only things that slow down a point-lookup are size of the index column(s) and the complexity of `COLLATION` (if a text type).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By converting to `BINARY(16)`, it becomes smaller and readily indexed.

V7 is naturally ordered chronologically.  V1's bits can be shuffled See 8.0's functions, 10.7's datatype and [*UUIDs*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/uuid) .

None of the other versions have the "chronological" characteristic.

Since the only way to lookup UUIDs is one row at a time, your comments about 'indexability' don't make sense.  Perhaps you were referring to "locality of reference" wherein all the "recent" rews will be "next" to each other.